# Replace Windows 10 with RemixOS

Tags: windows, windows-10, compaq-laptop

I have an HP Compaq Mini 110 with Windows 10 installed. It is quite an old computer, and Windows runs extremely slowly. I was wondering if it is possible to replace Windows with an installation of the Android-based RemixOS, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help.

*Note: I do not want to dual boot. The laptop has only 8GB of storage and I would like to completely replace the Windows installation (there are no files on it that I need to preserve).*

Comment: But wouldn't you be limited to install apps only from Google Play?

Comment: @Alexiy No, just limited to Android apps. However, I received the laptop for free and have no use for it as-is due to how slow it is.

Answer (score 1):

The laptop has an Atom processor which is from the [x86 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom#32-bit_and_64-bit_hardware_support).

> Intel® Atom™ N280 1.66-GHz processor, 512-KB Level 2 cache, 533-MHz front-side bus (FSB)
>
> Intel Atom N270 1.6-GHz processor, 512-KB Level 2 cache, 533-MHz front-
> side bus (FSB)
> ([source](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01757458.pdf))

It appears that RemixOS has a [version](http://www.jide.com/remixos-for-pc) for the x86 chipset. They don't specifically mention your laptop but I can't see a problem installing it.

Comment: I can install RemixOS on the laptop, I want to know if it's possible to replace the Windows installation completely.

Comment: The installation guide on the RemixOS page I linked seems to suggest that you can do a full installation.

Comment: Using the RemixOS installer (as they instruct) I installed RemixOS as as a second OS. It did not replace Windows.

Comment: That is out of scope for the current question (you only asked if it were possible), maybe you could ask another one about removing the Windows partition.

Comment: I updated the question to also ask how, since apparently it was necessary.